# Cannot open Spec to run tests

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
  rspec --seed=123 spec/spec_helper.rb
 I, [2015-12-14T17:13:54.178156 #11515]  INFO -- : Not reporting to Code    
Climate because ENV['CODECLIMATE_REPO_TOKEN'] is not set.
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00015 seconds (files took 0.6297 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 123
```

How to solve? i want t run test for my policy and my spec file not getting access.

Comment: Please don't edit your questions in a way that they completely change their initial intend. Instead, ask a new question. Also, please mark answers that solve your question as accepted by clicking on the green checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

You are only executing your `spec_helper.rb` file, which usually contains no test examples.

Try running `rspec --seed=123 spec/` to run all `*_spec.rb` files inside the `spec/` directory.

Comment: whats does this error means "# JobPolicy admin should permit action :cancel ". i am testing my policy and this keeps coming in

Comment: This seems to be an error from your application or your tests, and would be specific to what you've built - I have no way of knowing what's causing this.